# Read function for botocore.response.StreamingBody silently failing in lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to the data of an object in S3 in my lambda function with the following code:

```
session = boto3.Session()
s3d = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the S3 bucket and object name from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    objectKey = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    print(bucket)
    print(objectKey)
    
    content_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket, objectKey)
    file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read(None).decode('utf-8')
    metadata = json.loads(file_content)
```

I know from logging debug messages that this is failing on the read() function. I've tried putting it in a try/except block and printing the error, but that isn't working. I'm able to get `content_object.get()['Body']` by itself and confirm it is a botocore.response.StreamingBody object, and so the .read function should return all of the data according to [the docs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html). Instead, the lambda is failing silently.

Comment: try read() without the None, provided the bucket and key are correct, and the file has data.

Comment: @JonathanLeon file has data and bucket and key I've checked repeatedly through logging. I was originally trying read() without the None, but saw a post somewhere (don't recall where) implying you should pass None. With or without None, I get the same result.